# Wordpress - combine first name and last name

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, umbraco-ucommerce

I am using ucommerce from Wordpress.

I'm also using a plugin called 'Ultimate Member', which is divided into Last name and First name.

I deleted the Last name field and unified it into one(only first name),

but existing users are joined with two fields.

May I combine the first, last name fields of existing users?

Should I handle it in mysql?

Comment: Hint: `CONCAT(firstname, lastname)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's the part of mysql that solves it. Thank you,:)

Comment: If you had posted a query attempt, I would have posted an answer, but in any case glad you are now unblocked :-)